# day and month are swapped?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column 'C' containing dates and in that some cell values are having values like " **Due on Date"**. I have written  app script code that if a cell value contains "Due on" it will be copied to another column,else copied to different column.But on running I found that cells having **"due on "** on running the date and month are interchanged. for eg: if a cell contains "Due on 08/02/2022(dd/MM/yyyy)" is changed to "02/08/2022(MM/dd/yyyy)". Is there any method to retain the same date format.I have already done the date format methods in the spreadsheet and maintained the same time zone .
Here is the sample code:

```
  for(var i=value.length-1;i>=0;i--){
   var chn = value[i];
   if(chn[2]!="NA"){
   // var rdate= new Date(chn[2]);
    var dat=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(chn[2]), "GMT+5:30", "dd-MMMM-yyyy");
    var mat= chn[2].toString();
    if(mat.match(/Due on/)){
     var d1= mat.replace("Due on", "");
     var ds = new Date(dat);
     var year = ds.getFullYear();
     var month = ds.getDate();
     var day = ds.getMonth();
     Logger.log(chn[2]);
     Logger.log(dat);
     Logger.log(ds);
     Logger.log(month);
    // var pubdate = new Date(year, day,month);
    // Logger.log(pubdate);
     ss.getRange("C"+(i+2)).setValue("Valid till "+Utilities.formatDate(ds, "GMT+5:30", "dd-MMMM-yyyy"));
    }
    else{
     .................
    }
    }
```

A copy of the spreadsheet and the executions log is attached here:
[image]

Execution log:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You code works for me correctly, however here are some thoughts for troubleshooting

- You do not specify into which sheet you want to write (I assume `ss` is `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`). This is dangerous when your spreadsheet has several sheets. It's best to sue the method [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- Reduce your code snippet to something simpler to reduce potential error sources
- Change you spreadsheet [locale](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cchange-locale-and-time-zone) for changing the date formatting
- Since your date is concatenated to a string (and the method [formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) returns a date anyway), the output should not be affected by any locales and date formatting, however to be sure, try to set it explicitly to a string.
- Make sure you pass to `new Date()` a valid date object or date string.

This code snippet works for me regardless of the spreadsheet locale and the number formatting of the cells:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  for(var i = 10; i >= 0; i--){
    var dat=Utilities.formatDate(new Date("2022-05-15"), "GMT+5:30", "dd-MMMM-yyyy");
    ss.getRange("C"+(i+2)).setValue(("Due on  " + dat).toString());
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If the problem is the format of the original date string, you need to convert it to the necessary format for [new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date). To do so, you need to know the formatting of the original date string.

For a date string with the format `ddmmyyyy` , you can do it as following:

```js
  var chn = [];
  chn[2] =  "15052022";
  var day = Number(chn[2].substring(0,2));
  var month = Number(chn[2].substring(2,4));
  var year = Number(chn[2].substring(4,8));
  console.log("day: " + day)
  console.log("month: " + month)
  console.log("year: " + year)
  var dat= Utilities.formatDate(new Date(year, month - 1, day), "GMT+5:30", "dd-MMMM-yyyy");
  ss.getRange("C2").setValue(("Due on  " + dat).toString());
```

Comment: error still occurs when date is 15/05/2022 it is showing as january 01 1970 whereas for 08/02/2022 it is showing as february 8 2022. I have set the cell format as date dd/MM/yyyy.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem now. It is due to `chn[2]` not being a valid date object date string. Unfortunately I do not know where you retrieve this value and what it looks like, but keep in mind that for using the method `new Date()` you need to provide it a valid date object, e.g. in the format `2022-05-15` or `2020, 4, 15` - see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date). If `chn[2]` does not have the correct format, you need to convert it manually a valid date string.

Comment: chn[2] is user input value,it either has a “date” or “due on date” as value . The error is with due on date value bcoz  code donot read it as ddmmyyyy. If day is greater than 12th it read jan 1 1970 . The issue is with reading the date .

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you. Have you solved the issue now or do you need help with changing the data format?

Comment: No the issue is not resolved the date format is not resolved .can you help me how to convert this date format ,still any date of 12th or more is read as jan 1 1970 still now

Comment: I updated my answer with a sample code snippet.